# How to do numeric comparison on strings

Tags: ruby, rspec, serverspec

I have written a serverspec test which is intended to check if the amount of ram on a server is greater or equal than the mount listed in a properties file

```
   describe command('perl -n -e "if (/MemTotal:\s+(\d+)/) { print \$1; last; }" /proc/meminfo') do
     its(:stdout){ should be >= "#{property['ram']}"}
    end
```

On the machine I am testing on the command gives "7539944"

If property ram is set to "888" then the test incorrectly fails as with a string comparison "888" is greater than "7539944"

Is there someway I can make a numeric comparison on a string type in serverspec?

This irb session shows how I believe ruby is behaving and how I would like it to behave

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p484 :001 > prop="888"
 => "888" 
1.9.3-p484 :002 > command="7539944"
 => "7539944" 
1.9.3-p484 :003 > command > prop
 => false 
1.9.3-p484 :004 > command.to_i > prop.to_i
 => true
```

If i alter the describe to this

```
describe command('perl -n -e "if (/MemTotal:\s+(\d+)/) { print \$1; last; }" /proc/meminfo') do
 its(:stdout){ should be >= "#{property['ram']}".to_i}
end
```

I get this error

```
Failures:

      1) std Command "perl -n -e "if (/MemTotal:\s+(\d+)/) { print \$1; last; }" /proc/meminfo" stdout should be >= 888
         On host `foo.bar.org'
         Failure/Error: its(:stdout){ should be >= "#{property['ram']}".to_i}
         ArgumentError:
           comparison of String with 888 failed
           sudo -p 'Password: ' /bin/sh -c perl\ -n\ -e\ \"if\ \(/MemTotal:\\s\+\(\\d\+\)/\)\ \{\ print\ \\\$1\;\ last\;\ \}\"\ /proc/meminfo
           7539944
         Shared Example Group: "ram::init" called from ./spec/std/spec.rb:5
         # ./spec/shared/ram/init.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I think you gave the answer yourself: if you want to compare strings as integers, convert the strings to integers with `.to_i`.

Comment: `should be >= property['ram'].to_i` ; does it work?

Comment: I don't know how to make the its(:stdout) into an integer or even get a value out of it. ``>= property['ram'].to_i `` is fine for the RHS but gives a type error as the LHS is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool runs over old good `rspec`. It’s DSL is not needed to perform this task:

```
context 'memory' do
  it "should be greater than #{888}" do
    expect(`cat /proc/meminfo`[/MemTotal:\s+(\d+)/, 1].to_i).to be >= 888 
  end 
end
```

Perl invocation from ruby made my day, btw.

**UPD** I played a bit with `serverspec` and I could not find any straight implementation of your requirement. Hence, I would suggest you to monkeypatch `String` that way:

```
class String
  def greater_than? other
    to_i > other.to_i rescue false
  end
end
```

That way you will be able to write in your scenario:

```
its(:stdout) { should be_greater_than "#{property['ram']}" }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: not sure that I can use backticks like that in the serverspec thing.  The ``command`` "type" is wrapped and runs via ssh on a remote.  the ssh'ing is controlled by serverspec.  Glad you liked the perl :)

Comment: thx! that works and I like it.  Of course I also found another solution.  Using the "expect" syntax instead of "should" ``expect(subject.stdout.to_i).to be >= "#{property['ram']}".to_i`` does work.  Couldn't work out how to do this with "should"

Comment: I doubt you’ll succeed, that’s why `should` syntax was changed to `expect` in modern `rspec`s.